# Wick contraction on boldface symbols

Tags: math-mode, packages, math-operators

How can I Wick contract boldface letters?

I am currently using the wick.sty package but it does not allow either {\bf X} nor {\bf X} to be Wick contracted against anything else. Is there some way around it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package does not seem to be on CTAN, thus I found this [`wick.sty`](http://www2.yukawa.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~taichiro.kugo/macro/wick.sty).
A protected macro instead of `\mathbf` and additional braces for starting or ending points helped in the example from `wick.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wick}

\newcommand{\wickbold}{}% Check that \wickbold is undefined
\protected\def\wickbold#1{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \wick{213}{\wickbold{A} <1B CD <+{\wickbold{E}} FG >1H \wickbold{I}J %
    <xK L\wickbold{M} >+O PQ >x{\wickbold{R}} ST}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]